# What user am I when I upload a file to a S3 bucket with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli, localstack

I'm learning `AWS` using the `AWS` CLI and `LocalStack`.

I'm working with tutorials such as [this](https://dev.to/goodidea/how-to-fake-aws-locally-with-localstack-27me), which describe how to create a `S3` bucket and upload a file to it.

What I'd like to understand is the role of users in relation to `AWS` commands, and whether or not there is a relationship between a user and a profile (the latter is created when you run the `aws configure` CLI command).

When I run a `AWS` CLI command such as `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 cp ./foo.json s3://my-bucket/path/to/foo.json` **what user am I running that command as?** I have not explicitly created any users using the `AWS IAM` CLI or by other means. **Is a profile implicitly a user?** I.e. when I run `aws configure`, does the `default` profile created mean a user named `default` is created in `AWS IAM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to check actually.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html

> Is a profile implicitly a user?

No, profile is just that - credentials profile. Whether it's a user or a role, AWS CLI doesn't care as long as those credentials are valid.

> when I run aws configure, does the default profile created mean a user named default is created in AWS IAM

Going from previous point, no. Nothing is done implicitly in IAM. When you run `aws configure` you supply credentials that already exist, not the other way around.

Comment: `aws iam get-user` would get you the same information as `get-caller-identity` with couple of additional data points, such as user name and creation date